# Наклон устройства

Tags: javascript, cordova

Ребят, столкнулся с такой проблемой. Делаю приложение на cordova. Необходимо получить угол наклона  по оси х,у,z. Соответсвенно, взял кордововский плагин device-orientation. Но на выходе получаю не то. Он мне показывает отклонения относительно магнитного полюса. А когда идет смена ориентации - вообще совсем другие цифры. Подскажите, может формула есть какая или рещение, как мне получать абсолютные данные? Т.е.не важно, к северу девайс повернут или к югу. Типа нажал кнопку и текущее положение девайса - ноль,а вот если начнет им двигать пользователь, то получать данные относительно этого нуля? И соответственно, если пользователь сменил опиентацию - то опять сброс на ноль и данные от нуля?

Comment: есть кто живой?

Comment: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device-motion